# Java Script, Difficulty getting list of all nested frames in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey, frames

Hello I need to get list of all frames for my **GreaseMonkey** script but in fact i guess it is **general Javascript question**. It would be great if I could get to every single frame that is nested in page. So far i got problem getting number of frames nested in main document frames.

Page I'm dealing with consist of **frameset** that is **multilevel** and frames contains other frames. I've managed to get information about top-level frames of main document frameset (in code **level 1**) but at this level i get information that frame count for these frames equals 0 which is not true.

I've came up with following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var frames = window.frames;
var i,j;
var reportText = "level 0 > " + frames.length +"\r\n";

for (i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
    var frames2 = frames[i].frames;
    reportText += "level 1 - " + i + " > " + frames[i].name + " - " + frames2.length +"\r\n";

    for (j = 0; j < frames2.length; j++) {
      var frames3 = frames2[j].frames; 
      reportText += "level 2 - " + i + " - " + j + " > "  + frames2[j].name + " - " + frames3.length +"\r\n";
    }
}

alert(reportText);});
```

So **level 0** which is in fact main document frame count and **level 1** names or main document frames - these things are reported correctly but not the amount of frames of each **level 1** frame. And i want to know if it is because my code got mistakes or maybe because subframes are not yest fully loaded.

I've tried to call my code from keyboard shortcut, after all will look like its completely loaded, but here another problem, seems like following code seems to not to work with page that consist only of frameset

```
 (function(){
 document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 72 && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && e.altKey && !e.metaKey) {
 
 //...my previous code inside document.ready...
 
   }
 }, false);})();
```

Best would be if code automatically comb through all frames and subframes but with its current shape (where each level got it own loop)  is also good.

Problem with inability of using shortcut key is secondary. **Main thing is getting proper counts of frames inside frames of main document and beyond.**

***EDIT:*** Sample output and My test page with nested frameset

**Output**

> level 0 > 3
>
> level 1 - 0 > main1 - 0
>
> level 1 - 1 > main2 - 0
>
> level 1 - 2 > main3 - 0

**Test page with nested frameset**

**frame0.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
  <frame id="frmain1" name="main1" src="frame0_1.htm">
  <frame id="frmain2" name="main2" src="frame0_2.htm">
  <frame id="frmain3" name="main3" src="frame0_3.htm">
</frameset>
</html>
```

**frame0_1.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<frameset rows="25%,*">
  <frame id="frsub11" name="sub11" src="frame0_1_1.htm">
  <frame id="frsub12" name="sub12" src="frame0_1_2.htm">
</frameset>
</html>
```

**frame0_1_1.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background: darkorange;">
</body>
</html>
```

**frame0_1_2.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background: lightyellow;">
</body>
</html>
```

**frame0_2.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<frameset rows="25%,*,25%">
  <frame id="frsub21" name="sub21" src="frame0_2_1.htm">
  <frame id="frsub22" name="sub22" src="frame0_2_2.htm">
  <frame id="frsub23" name="sub23" src="frame0_2_3.htm">
</frameset>
</html>
```

**frame0_2_1.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background: skyblue;">
</body>
</html>
```

**frame0_2_2.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background: cornflowerblue;">
</body>
</html>
```

**frame0_2_3.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background: slateblue;">
</body>
</html>
```

**frame0_3.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<frameset rows="25%,*">
  <frame id="frsub31" name="sub31" src="frame0_3_1.htm">
  <frame id="frsub32" name="sub32" src="frame0_3_2.htm">
</frameset>
</html>
```

**frame0_3_1.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background: darkgreen;">
</body>
</html>
```

**frame0_3_2.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background: lightgreen;">
    <a id="test" href="http://www.google.com">testlink</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If any of your frames are from a different domain, you won't have access to their contents (and hence sub-frames). Also you have an obvious error in your code here: `frames2[j].frames.lenght`.

Comment: @jcaron Thanks for pointing out mistake, though this part of code doesn't had chance to execute when one step before 0 frame count is reported. I'am aware of same origin policy and this is not the case here. Still i have not a clue why i can't get count of frames inside frames of main document frameset.

Comment: Is your code executed at all? Add logs (using `console.log`, which you'll be able to see in your browser console) at different places to see which parts are executed, and log relevant data. That would be a lot more convenient than an `alert`.

Comment: @jcaron Yes it executes, in this case alert was more convenient for me. I've added sample output and page with nested frameset that i use for testing purposes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is the event on which you call this. `$(document).ready()` is fired when the current DOM has been loaded. So it's triggered when the 3 main frames are loaded. But at this point these frames didn't load their `iframes` yet. By changing the event to **window.onload**, you should have the expected result. Like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    ...
```

or

```
window.onload = function(){
    ...
```

See **window.onload**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images, scripts, links and **sub-frames** have finished loading.

See https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Can you also take a look on thing I came across by the way of trying to solve my problem, I mean `document.addEventListener` does not work while using on document that consist only of frameset, and share your thoughts about it?

Comment: The problem with keydown listener (or any event that you apply on window or document), is that these events will be triggered on one of the sub frames, not on the top window. You could add these events on these sub frames, but you'll still need them to be loaded, so your back with the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

**Working Code Solution**

Use a recursive function and the `window` `load` event, like so (works in latest versions of Chrome, FireFox and Edge; didn't test others. Probably works in IE5+ also).

Use this code in your top level `frameset`, *frame0.htm*:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML Frameset DTD>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function()
{
    var allFrames = [];
    function recursFrames(context)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < context.frames.length; i++)
        {
            console.log(context.frames[i].name + " -- " + context.frames[i].location.href);
            allFrames.push(context.frames[i]);
            recursFrames(context.frames[i]);
        }
    }
    recursFrames(window);
    console.log("Frames count: " + allFrames.length);
}
</script>
</head>
<frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
  <frame id="frmain1" name="main1" src="frame0_1.htm">
  <frame id="frmain2" name="main2" src="frame0_2.htm">
  <frame id="frmain3" name="main3" src="frame0_3.htm">
</frameset>
</html>
```

This writes to the console just to show you what is going on, but of course you can do whatever you want with this information. It creates a flat list (array) of all child frames, but you could structure it hierarchically if you like, or whatever.

**HTML 5 Reminder**

You are using the HTML5 `DOCTYPE`, but `frameset` is not supported by HTML5. But it is up to the browser to decide when to stop supporting this, and many of them still do. I recommend you stop using `frameset` ASAP. Use `iframe` instead if you need frame-like behavior (different windows and documents).

Comment: I didn't do anything with shortcut key handler, but you said this was secondary and I'm not clear on what you are doing there.. sounds like you were just trying to use it for testing, but please let me know if you are still having trouble with this. Also, this solution uses native javascript, but you can of course replace with jQuery if desired.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, thing is I'm improving some existing web app that is based on frames -  i don't have access to source itself only way i can improve it is with GreaseMonkey and user defined script - so that is why I'm insisting on dealing with `frames` instead of `iframes`. And yes because of jQuery flexibility i will use it instead native JS. Thanks once again!

Comment: Makes sense - I have run into similar situations myself when updating legacy products. Thanks for satisfying my curiosity. Let me know if you have any issues with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

[frameset](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp) is not supported in  [html5](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp).

Please see the following demo: [frameset Demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dungiod2asl15g/framsets.zip?dl=0). I have modified htm files. The idea is to listen to frameset onload event and access its contents after onlnoad event is fired.

In order to access content of child frame, [Same-Origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) must be invoked.

Comment: Thanks for answer, thing is that dealing with `frames` is not up to me, i try to improve user side of existing system with web interface. So in fact I'm forced to deal with bunch of nested `frames`.